# AWS RDS workbench connection issue

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, workbench

I have been using AWS for 2 years. I have not encountered an error like this, the connection between workbench and Amazon RDS was flawless until yesterday, It is showing:

> error 10060: no database found

However I am certain that the database endpoint URL is not changed. But anyway I checked my connection once again it was showing the same error. Then I deleted the database configuration in workbench and try to connect again it worked and when I closed and try open again it is showing the same error 10060. I have tried every inbound and outbound rule in the RDS configuration. I never had an issue before but now I don't know why it's happening.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Does it take a long time (eg 10+ seconds) to fail (suggesting no network connectivity), or does it fail immediately (suggesting incorrect credentials)? Are you connecting from your own computer (outside of AWS)? Have you checked the configuration of the **Security Group** on the database? It might be that your personal IP address has changed, so the Security Group is now blocking it.

Comment: Did you try with telnet, nc, curl ... to make sure that you are able to connect to that endpoint? If you cannot, just check what John Rotenstein recommend (go to AWS console and check them).

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved. The AWS system was down around Christmas time. So my workbench couldn't able to connect to the server.